# How can the median number of sexual partners be 6.1 and 3.6?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg/key_statistics/n.htm

Median number of female sexual partners in lifetime, for men 25-44 years of age, 2006-2008: 6.1

Wouldn't it only be able to be x.5 or x.0?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, then [median of a sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Medians_for_samples) is either one of the possible sample values or the arithmetic mean of two sample values. Hence if all sample values are integers, it is an integer or half-integer. Specifically, numbers like 6.1 are not possible as sample median of "number of (whatever)".

Comment: While I agreed with you, I can't imagine the CDC doesn't know how to do medians?

Comment: @user248640: Perhaps they're running their raw data through a process that thinks they are a discretization of continuously distributed samples, and then tries to estimate the median of the underlying smooth distribution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That would mean they do not only use the wrong tool, but do not even notice that the output is not compatible with what they ask for, so they make, like, three statistics beginner's error at once?

Comment: If you check the references, you’ll find that they are estimating medians (and providing standard errors for the estimates) from weighted data obtained from a complex sample design.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the sample is comstructed out of sets of grouped data rather than individual integer values only. Therefore this figure could legitimately be arrived at by linear interpolation.

For example, it is quite likely that the questionnaire would involve ticking boxes such as "zero", "between 1 and 5" or similar.

After all, would you expect that all respondents be able to give an accurate integer value as a response if that value is large?